# Find $x$ such that $\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\cdots}}}=10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I've tried this. Raise
$$
y := \sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\cdots}}}=10
$$
to the third power, which yields:
$$
y^3=x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[3]{x\cdots}}}=xy=10^3.
$$
Using that $y=10$ we have
$$
10x=10^3 \implies x=10^2.
$$
Is this procedure okay?

Comment: Yes. Looks fine

Comment: That's part of it.  If it converges, then the limit is $10$.  You also need the other part: to show that it does converge when $x=10^2$.

Comment: The approach (which yields the right answer) is sort of fine, but assumes the expression defines a real number. I would prefer an argument that also  proves convergence.

Comment: Could you hint me how to start the proof of convergence? I understand convergence just fine when dealing with series, but this isn't a series (or is it)? @AndréNicolas

Comment: As implicitly mentioned in the answer, an "infinitely often iterated  roots" expression of the general type of the one in the problem is said to converge if the sequence obtained at truncating just before the second root, just before the third, and so on.  This is in analogy with the usual partial sums definition of convergence of an infinite sum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it would be nice to show that the expression defines a real number for suitable $x$. If we truncate at various points, we get the expressions $x^{1/3}$, $x^{1/3+1/9}$, $x^{1/3+1/9+1/27}$, and so on. For non-negative $x$ this converges to $x$ to the power $1/3+1/9+1/27+1/81+\cdots$. The geometric series has sum $1/2$.